# Android gradient background looks banded and all the methods suggested in similar issue do not work

Tags: android, background, gradient

I am applying a gradient background to my activity and it appears with ugly bands in the emulator.
I have done my research and the fix proposed (10 years ago) do not work for me, that is using the dither attribute or adding setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888) on activity creation.

See my background drawable:

> ```
> android:shape="rectangle">
> <gradient
>     android:startColor="#FE000000"
>     android:endColor="#FE59656C"
>     android:angle="90"
>     android:type="linear"
>     android:useLevel="true"
>     android:dither="true"/> </shape>
> ```

Initially there was no type/uselevel/dither and "FE" alpha but Ive read it might help, but it does not.
Also I have added teh following to my activity:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onAttachedToWindow() {
>     super.onAttachedToWindow();
>     Window window = getWindow();
>     window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
> }
> ```

Finally my layout has:

> android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"

Comment: have you tried this on real device to see if that works fine or not ?

Comment: I did and it looks plain with no bands but when sharing with someone on internet and downloading from there shows bands.